# No xaml color formatting in visual studio 2012

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012

This is the second time i have installed VS 2012 and the first time the color formatting for xaml was working but not anymore. If i can change some element in the tools -> fonts and colors but i cant get the normal default scheme back with the blue | red | yellow look, even if i change back to defaults.

Any help would be nice. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that `*.xaml` files are loaded but appear as if it's a plain text document (i.e. black-on-white)?

Comment: Well the designer displays for the *.xaml document but the text editor has no color formatting. Even if i change colors in the options environment. The only color that changes is the main font color but nothing else. If i try change the comment color it just stays the same as the color that is defined for the main font, which all the text is.

Comment: Try to re-install again VS2012

Comment: I have twice. I also did the whole repair thing

Comment: Have you tried Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts & Colors and in the 'Display items' list scroll down to the XAML items and click 'Use defaults'? Or running "devenv /resetuserdata" in a command prompt? Also, I'm confused, how can you offer a bounty of 50 when you only have 33? Interesting...

Comment: I do not see any options for Xaml in the Display items. There is only XML near the bottom. Well I had 73 . I am guessing the points are removed once the bounty is put in place not once i have given it out.

Comment: Do you have any plug-ins installed? ReSharper or CodeRush?

Comment: I do yes ... not coderush or resharper but others. The thing is that when i installed it, before i had added the extensions its was just plain colorless xaml. I think my pc is up for a reformat.

Comment: @ChrisW. - Thanks - "devenv /resetuserdata" worked for me.

Comment: The other thing you can do is change your theme from light -> dark or dark -> light and back.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've had this exact same issue. The solution is:

- close all running instances of Visual Studio
- open a "Run" window and type in `devenv /resetuserdata`

That's it. Open your projects again and everything should work fine.
Beware: your personal settings will be lost. Recently opened projects list also.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the .xaml file -> open with option from the list choose HTML Editor With Encoding

Answer (score 0):

You can try Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts & Colors and Display Items as Use Defaults..as suggested by gerdi...Also make sure all options are ticked Under  Tools -> Options -> TextEditor -> General...

Comment: I am gerdi .. gerdi created this question outlining that this did not work. Thanks though