# XAML file formatting issue with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I have installed VS 2015 Enterprise edition on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine.
Initially after installation I was not able to create a WPF project using the specified template. I re-installed it as suggested in the error and it started working fine. But now a new issue has popped up.

My .xaml files are without any color formatting.

I have tried all the solutions mentioned in a parallel post but to no success
[No xaml color formatting in visual studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582209/no-xaml-color-formatting-in-visual-studio-2012)

Any help is appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The last time this happened, I just did Tools-> Options-> Environment-> Fonts and Colors-> Settings for "Text Editor" choosing "Use Defaults" like shown below;

[image]

Or there's a bunch of editor themes available in the extensions gallery also. Hope this helps.

Comment: W: I dont have XAML attributes in Text Editor Display Items list.
But I did installed resharper today and it miraculously fixed it!!! :)

P.S. Will worry about this after some days....